# Qt, issue with modifying a widgets properties outside the constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering if anybody could tell me whats actually going on here. I have included the header and implementation file for a simple config dialog. The problem is in the updateAutoSaveGroupBox slot I cannot access or change any properties of my widgets on the page. I.E. I want to make some widgets disabled if a check box has not been checked but when I try to set them I get a read access violation. Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated. The problems exsist in these two lines(commented out so it will run for now without throwing an exception).

```
//autoSaveLabel->setDisabled(autoSaveIsEnabled);
//autoSaveSpinBox->setDisabled(getAutoSaveIsEnabled());
```

configWidget.h

```
class EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
~EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget();

signals:
void setAutoSaveIsEnabledSignal(bool autoSaveIsEnabled);

public slots:
void setAutoSaveIsEnabled(bool autoSaveIsEnabled){_AutoSaveIsenabled = autoSaveIsEnabled;}
bool getAutoSaveIsEnabled(){return _AutoSaveIsenabled;}

void updateAutoSaveGroupBox(bool autoSaveIsEnabled);

private:
void makeConnections();
void readSettings();
void writeSettings();
void createMainWidget();

QGroupBox *uiGroupBox;
QStringList localList;
QLabel *localLabel;
QComboBox *localeComboBox;
QHBoxLayout *localSelectionHLayout;
QGroupBox *systemGroupBox;
QCheckBox *autoSaveCheckBox;
QLabel *autoSaveLabel;
QSpinBox *autoSaveSpinBox;
QHBoxLayout *autoSaveHLayout;

bool _AutoSaveIsenabled;
};
```

ConfigWidget.cpp

```
#include "enigmaconfiggeneralenvironmentwidget.h"

#include <QtWidgets>

EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget::EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)
{
makeConnections();
readSettings();

createMainWidget();
}

EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget::~EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget()
{
writeSettings();
}

void EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget::makeConnections()
    {connect(this,SIGNAL(setAutoSaveIsEnabledSignal(bool)),this,SLOT(setAutoSaveIsEnabled(bool))    );
connect(this,SIGNAL(setAutoSaveIsEnabledSignal(bool)),this,SLOT(updateAutoSaveGroupBox(bool))    );
}

void EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget::readSettings()
{
QSettings settings;
settings.beginGroup(tr("UI.Config.Environment.General"));
bool autoSaveIsEnabled = settings.value("autoSaveIsEnabled",bool(true)).toBool();
setAutoSaveIsEnabledSignal(autoSaveIsEnabled);
settings.endGroup();
}

void EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget::writeSettings()
{
QSettings settings;
settings.beginGroup(tr("UI.Config.Environment.General"));
settings.setValue("autoSaveIsEnabled",getAutoSaveIsEnabled());
settings.endGroup();
}

void EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget::createMainWidget()
{
localList.append(tr("Danish - ???"));
localList.append(tr("English - Australia"));
localList.append(tr("English - Canada"));
localList.append(tr("English - USA"));
localList.append(tr("English - UK"));
localList.append(tr("Finnish - Finland"));
localList.append(tr("French - Canada"));
localList.append(tr("French - France"));
localList.append(tr("Norwegian - ???"));
localList.append(tr("Swedish - ???"));

uiGroupBox = new QGroupBox();
uiGroupBox->setTitle(tr("UI Settings"));

localLabel= new QLabel();
localLabel->setText(tr("Select a language: "));

localeComboBox = new QComboBox();
localeComboBox->addItems(localList);

localSelectionHLayout = new QHBoxLayout(uiGroupBox);
localSelectionHLayout->addWidget(localLabel);
localSelectionHLayout->addWidget(localeComboBox);

systemGroupBox = new QGroupBox();
systemGroupBox->setTitle(tr("System Settigns"));

autoSaveCheckBox = new QCheckBox();
autoSaveCheckBox->setText(tr("Auto-Save Enabled: "));
autoSaveCheckBox->setChecked(getAutoSaveIsEnabled());
        connect(autoSaveCheckBox,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SIGNAL(setAutoSaveIsEnabledSignal(bool)));
autoSaveLabel = new QLabel(this);
autoSaveLabel->setText(tr("Auto-Save Interval is Every: "));

autoSaveSpinBox = new QSpinBox();
autoSaveSpinBox->setSuffix(tr("Mins."));
autoSaveSpinBox->setAccelerated(true);

autoSaveHLayout = new QHBoxLayout(systemGroupBox);
autoSaveHLayout->addWidget(autoSaveCheckBox);
autoSaveHLayout->addWidget(autoSaveLabel);
autoSaveHLayout->addWidget(autoSaveSpinBox);

QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
vLayout->addWidget(uiGroupBox);
vLayout->addWidget(systemGroupBox);
}

void EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget::updateAutoSaveGroupBox(bool autoSaveIsEnabled)
{
qDebug() << "debug " << autoSaveIsEnabled;
//autoSaveLabel->setDisabled(autoSaveIsEnabled);
//autoSaveSpinBox->setDisabled(getAutoSaveIsEnabled());
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong from a quick glance. Try to run your program in GDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotted it:

```
void EnigmaConfigGeneralEnvironmentWidget::readSettings()
{
QSettings settings;
settings.beginGroup(tr("UI.Config.Environment.General"));
bool autoSaveIsEnabled = settings.value("autoSaveIsEnabled",bool(true)).toBool();
setAutoSaveIsEnabledSignal(autoSaveIsEnabled);
settings.endGroup();
}
```

You are calling `void setAutoSaveIsEnabledSignal(bool)` here (the signal), not `void setAutoSaveIsEnabled(bool)` (the actual setter). Hence the member variable is still uninitialized.

Reminder for yourself: Don't name signals as if they were setters, use e.g. `void autoSaveIsEnabledChanged(bool)`

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix the problem, but could you explain. I've done this the same way in other parts of my program without resistance, why here would it be a problem? My thinking was to set a signal to the setter slot and for uniformity, just always call the signal that way no slot had to be called directly, they could be called from the same signals that already were connected to other widgets.

Comment: Well, no idea. But why is it an issue to call a slot directly? Going via signals adds another roundtrip.

Comment: It's just that those signals are already required for the signal/slot connection method on some of my widgets and actions, so I just figured since I already used signals in some instances, it would just be the most convinent method to always call those signals to preform the task

Comment: Well, but why is it convenient? It also adds another roundtrip via QMetaObject::invokeMethod, etc. pp.. Just calling the setter directly *is convenient*.

Comment: I mean as convention for writing style. While the performance is a factor, on something like this it is small in comparison to the advantage of keeping a small team all very new to QT on the same page. I am as well a young programmer without a lot of experience or finished projects and without the completion of a project the performance does not matter at all, so I am really focusing on why it is syntactically wrong. I will work on optimizations after I know more and once I actually have something to optimize, although having said that you could be right and I could just be over-thinking it.

Comment: And I mean convenient by convention. Not by the literal call but the fact that all calls happen the same.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're really *over-thinking it* a bit. Your version wasn't syntactically wrong, it was just more complex than it needed to be, hence it got error-prone. Try to keep code simple.

I suggest going through some Qt examples to get a feeling for it.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the advise and help, and I think I will do just that.

Comment: Although looking at it now, what criteria do you use to decide when a function should be declared as a slot or normally as a function. when-ever a function needs to be connected by a signal it just gets promoted to a slot? Or are all getters and setters just natural slots.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24395/discussion-between-rob-and-kfunk)